# How to show a message when Alt is pressed in C# using KeyPress event?

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I would like to show a message when Alt is pressed using KeyPress event in Windows Form Applications and C#. The following code is only working with Shift and Control, but is not working with Alt. It is not giving me an error but it is not working when I am executing the program.

```
 public static System.Windows.Forms.Keys ModifierKeys
        {
            get;
        }
 private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {

            if((Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Alt) == Keys.Alt)
            
            {
                ((Control)sender).Hide(); 
                MessageBox.Show("pppppppppppppppppppppp");
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `KeyDown` as it has the modifiers and special keys built in, the `Alt` key specifically is a non-char key.

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Alt)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Alt key was pressed down");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Key press event:**

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Modifiers == Keys.Alt)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Alt key pressed");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: that won't work, it will error https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0221

Comment: ```KeyPressEventArgs``` doesn't have a ```Modifiers``` property.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.alt?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: that links to the ```KeyDown``` event while your answer is ```KeyPress``` event, the event args are different, have you actually tested your answer?

Comment: This is not working as well, it is giving me error under (char)Keys.Alt.``` private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Modifiers == Keys.Alt)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Alt key pressed");
        }
    }```